# MySQL: Check for numeric values and change "," to "."

Tags: mysql, replace, numeric

I got the following problem:

I am regularly uploading values into a MySQL database and have to check for numeric values (incl. float). Unfortunately some of these numeric values have been entered as for example **1,23** instead of **1.23**.

I now want MySQL to do a table update and change these values to true numeric values (**1.23**) for all values which are numeric after changing a possible "," to "."

Example:

> **Left, Right** should stay as **Left, Right**
>
> **120** should stay as **120**
>
> **2.5** should stay as **2.5**
>
> **0,125** should become **0.125**

Anyone got any idea?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is your system being used by people who have different decimal separators?

Comment: Could you please provide some more information regarding the column/s you wish to change?

Comment: You can create a trigger witch onUpdate and onInsert function will replace your number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if your column is form of numeric or not.. You can use MYSQL RLIKE operator which matches regular expressions for this kind of situations

```
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COL_NAME=replace(COL_NAME,  ','  , '.'  ) WHERE COL_NAME RLIKE '([0-9])+,([0-9])+'
```

Comment: I think that will do for me. I will give it a try

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE your_table
SET your_field = REPLACE(your_field, ',', '.')
WHERE your_field LIKE '%,%'